# Get an array containing the search word from a json array with jq

Tags: shell, json, jq

Given the following json data and "a" as a search word, how can I get the array `["a", "b", "c"]` containing the search word "a" using jq?

```
[
    ["a","b","c"],
    ["d","e","f"],
    ["g","h","i"]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this does what you want:

```
'.[]|select(index("a"))'
```

This applies `index("a")` to each sublist, which returns either the index of `a` in the list or `null`. Since `null` evaluates to false, using that as the `select()` condition finds only sublists that contain `a`.

Here it is in practice:

```
$ jq '.[]|select(index("a"))' <<EOF
> [
    ["a","b","c"],
    ["d","e","f"],
    ["g","h","i"]
]
EOF
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the top-level array could potentially contain *several* sub-arrays that contain the query string, I'm assuming that what you want is a top-level array with each sub-array that contains the query string:

```bash
jq 'map(select(any(index("a"))))' file
```

This selects each sub-array in which at least one ("any") element is the string `a`.  You could do away with wrapping `index()` inside `any()` and just use `map(select(index("a")))`, but using `any()` IMHO looks nicer from a linguistic point of view, and it also makes it almost identical to [my answer to your follow-up question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/712909/116858).