# Get an array containing partially matching search word from a json array with jq

Tags: shell, json, jq

Given the following json data and "a" as a partially matching search word, how can I get an array `["a", "b", "c"], ["abc", "e", "f"]` containing the partially matching search word "a" using jq?

```
[
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["abc", "e", "f"],
    ["g", "h", "i"]
]
```

`jq '. [] | select(index("a"))'` gets only `["a", "b", "c"]` with exact match, but I want to get `["abc", "e", "f"]` as well since "abc" contains "a".

Comment: If your [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/712797/4989) on this topic is answered you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get an array containing the search word from a json array with jq](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712797/get-an-array-containing-the-search-word-from-a-json-array-with-jq)

Answer (score 1):

```
jq '[.[] | select(contains(["a"]))]'
```

With your input array:

```
$ jq -c << \\ '[.[] | select(contains(["a"]))]'
[
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["abc", "e", "f"],
    ["g", "h", "i"]
]
\
[["a","b","c"],["abc","e","f"]]
```

`man jq` (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) is a bit long, but I think the relevant part is:

> The filter `contains(b)` will produce true if b is completely contained within the input. A string B is contained in a string A if B is a substring of A. An array B is contained in an array A if all elements in B are contained in any element in A.
>
> ```
> jq 'contains(["baz", "bar"])'
> Input  ["foobar", "foobaz", "blarp"]
> Output true
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach from [what rowboat took](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/712811/116858):

```bash
jq 'map(select(any(contains("a"))))' file
```

The innermost test tests each of the strings for the substring `a`. If any string in a sub-array contains `a`, that sub-array is selected. The `map` applies the selection to all sub-arrays in the top-level array.

The result is a top-level array with sub-arrays that contain at least one element that contains the substring `a`:

```json
[
  [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
  ],
  [
    "abc",
    "e",
    "f"
  ]
]
```